# Access denied in Apache using Django

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess, access-denied

I am trying to setup a Django project like [explained on AlwaysData](http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/Deploying_a_Django_App), but on my own computer.

I'm using ArchLinux.

I got an access denied in my error_log when I went to the directory containing the FastCGI script (the same django.fcgi as in the link above) :

```
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/home
```

However, I can access the project if I go to `directory/django.fcgi` instead of only `directory/`.

My .htaccess is :

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
Options +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex django.fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I comment the last line, I does not get the acces denied error and I can access my django project by both methods (`directory/` and `directory/django.fcgi`).

Nevertheless, I need the last line of this .htaccess to get clean URLs.

Do you know what is the problem in my configuration?

Comment: I finally used mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used mod_wsgi to solve my problem.